# Did a firmware update, now Mail.app crashes on start up -- full log provided -- help?

Tags: macos, mac, crash, email

I am running the latest Lion.  It just did a software update which provided a firmware update.

Now when I launch Mail.app it crashes on start up.  Specifically, the application window appears, and the "get mail" spinner spins, then it goes boom with the following details (can't provide full log because it's too long).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Process:         Mail [243]
Path:            /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier:      com.apple.mail
Version:         5.1 (1251)
Build Info:      Mail-1251000000000000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [121]

Date/Time:       2011-11-14 15:06:17.156 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.2 (11C74)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          50366 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           7
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  979175 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   7
Anonymous UUID:                      69376C6D-8F36-4B4E-AE0B-D12282A42C85

Crashed Thread:  11  -[SyncThreadController _doSyncWithSession:]  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff89f7dc30

VM Regions Near 0x7fff89f7dc30:
    __TEXT                 00007fff896ab000-00007fff89e00000 [ 7508K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
--> __TEXT                 00007fff89e00000-00007fff8a000000 [ 2048K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    Submap                 00007fff8a000000-00007fffc0000000          r--/rwx process-only submap

Application Specific Information:
objc[243]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9070567a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90704d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4b1b6c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4ba2d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4b9ae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff957463d3 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 277
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9574d63d ReceiveNextEventCommon + 355
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff9574d4ca BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff896b43f1 _DPSNextEvent + 659
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff896b3cf5 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 135
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff896b062d -[NSApplication run] + 470
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8992f80c NSApplicationMain + 867
12  com.apple.mail                  0x000000010ecd6d88 0x10ebfe000 + 888200

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff907077e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b75be _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b614e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90707192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6c594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6db85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9070567a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90704d71 mach_msg + 73
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4b1b6c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4ba2d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1204
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c4b9ae6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
5   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e67fc48 _handleRequestWithTimeout + 1484
6   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e682259 -[_NSSocket readBytes:length:error:] + 164
7   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e681e72 -[Connection _readBytesFromSocketIntoBuffer:amount:requireAllBytes:error:] + 86
8   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e681d04 -[Connection _fillBuffer:] + 673
9   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e681957 -[Connection _readLineIntoData:error:] + 74
10  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6818c9 -[IMAPConnection _readLineIntoData:error:] + 53
11  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e68176a -[IMAPConnection(MFPrivate) _readDataOfLength:intoData:error:] + 113
12  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6812aa -[IMAPResponse initWithConnection:error:] + 150
13  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6811da -[IMAPConnection _copyNextServerResponse:] + 56
14  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e68b8fc -[IMAPConnection _copyNextTaggedOrContinuationResponseForCommand:exists:] + 519
15  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e69a203 -[IMAPConnection _responseFromSendingOperation:] + 937
16  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e77ab94 -[IMAPConnection executeLogin:] + 62
17  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e777c08 -[IMAPClientLoginOperation executeOnConnection:] + 25
18  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6894bc -[IMAPConnection prepareAndExecuteOperation:outWrongState:] + 1485
19  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6889c6 -[IMAPGateway _allowClientOperationThrough:] + 855
20  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6883e2 -[IMAPGateway allowClientOperationThrough:] + 350
21  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e688257 -[IMAPClientOperation main] + 85
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92a6f788 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 705
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92a829e6 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 + 124
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b58ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b6799 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 255
26  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6c3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
27  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6db85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90706bca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6e274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92a8e675 -[__NSOperationInternal waitUntilFinished] + 138
3   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e78084b -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _pushFlags:forMessageIDs:toStore:updateServer:usingCriterion:withMonitor:] + 222
4   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e70bd2e -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _pushFlags:toStore:updateServer:withMonitor:] + 528
5   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6c8d21 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _syncWithLibraryWithMonitor:messagesFromOpen:] + 1524
6   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e6bff47 -[IMAPMailboxSyncEngine _goWithMessages:] + 729
7   com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e675f49 -[LibraryIMAPStore openSynchronouslyUpdatingMetadata:withOptions:] + 373
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c51720c __invoking___ + 140
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c5170a4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 132
10  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e661d3c -[MonitoredInvocation invoke] + 196
11  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e63e745 -[ThrowingInvocationOperation main] + 33
12  com.apple.MessageFramework      0x00007fff8e63e6eb -[_MFInvocationOperation main] + 449
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92a6f788 -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 705
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff92a829e6 ____NSOQSchedule_block_invoke_2 + 124
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b58ba _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 18
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff921b6799 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 255
17  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6c3da _pthread_wqthread + 316
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8fc6db85 start_wqthread + 13
```

[... much deleted ...]

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 4
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 446
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=225.1M resident=159.8M(71%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=65.2M(29%)
Writable regions: Total=148.1M written=28.9M(19%) resident=62.6M(42%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=85.5M(58%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG backing stores                   280K
CG image                            228K
CG raster data                      304K
CG shared images                   3408K
CoreGraphics                         16K
CoreImage                            76K
CoreServices                       2852K
MALLOC                            104.3M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)               4K        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Memory tag=240                        4K
Memory tag=242                       12K
Memory tag=251                      116K
OpenCL                               68K
SQLite page cache                  3360K
STACK GUARD                        56.1M
Stack                              20.3M
VM_ALLOCATE                        17.4M
__CI_BITMAP                          80K
__DATA                             23.9M
__IMAGE                            1256K
__LINKEDIT                         48.9M
__RC_CAMERAS                        236K
__TEXT                            176.2M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        53.7M
shared memory                       312K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             513.5M
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space    513.5M

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B24, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe, 256 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446393333334700000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446393333334700000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.100.98.75.18)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.1f4, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9A302, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0430  (Fujitsu Component Limited), 0x100e, 0xfa130000 / 6
USB Device: USB Mouse, 0x0566  (Monterey International Corp.), 0x4006, 0xfa132000 / 9
USB Device: Sun USB Keyboard, 0x0430  (Fujitsu Component Limited), 0x00a2, 0xfa134000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 7
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: iPad, apple_vendor_id, 0x129f, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI, I reinstalled Lion, problem is now gone.